# how to remove this incompatibility between tikz, bodegraph and tcblisting

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcblisting, bodegraph

Hello I want to plot some code examples of using the Bodegraph package with tcblisting.

The code below works fine if I put the semilog {} ... command in a scope environment, on the other hand if I put this command directly in the tikzpicture environment (commented code), everything crashes (I'm using Xelatex).

How to overcome this problem

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower,listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
righthand width=8cm}
\begin{scope}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
\end{scope} 
\end{tcblisting}


\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower,listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
righthand width=8cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,20);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{tcblisting}


\begin{tikzpicture}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
\end{tikzpicture} 

%\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower,listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
%righthand width=8cm}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
%\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
%\end{tikzpicture} 
%\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options `tikz lower`  and `tikz upper` automatically include "hidden"  `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` into the listing code. You can see it in corresponding examples in `tcolorbox` documentation.

So when you include these commands into the code, you are nesting `tikzpictures` which is not recommended. In your second example it works, but not with the last one.

The solution consist in avoiding those lines. Optional parameter that you add to `tikzpicture` environment, can be added to `tikz lower={...}`.

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower,listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
righthand width=8cm}
\begin{scope}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
\end{scope} 
\end{tcblisting}


\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower,listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
righthand width=8cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,20);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{tcblisting}


\begin{tikzpicture}
[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tcblisting}{tikz lower={yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5},listing side text,width=16cm,fonttitle=\bfseries,,colback=white,colframe=black,
righthand width=8cm}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2/30,xscale=7/5]
\semilog*{-2}{3}{-20}{10}
%\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]